# What is this value of k and what is the limit L?

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

There is exactly one value of the constant $k$ such that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{({{e^x}^2}−x^2−1)(\cos x−1)}{x^k}$$
is finite and nonzero. What is this value of $k$ and what is the limit $L$?

I have no idea how to solve this. I've tried using maclaurin series to solve this, but nothing seems to make sense. Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$e^{x^2} -x^2 - 1 = \frac{x^4}{2!} + O(x^6)$

$\cos x - 1 = \frac{-x^2}{2!} + O(x^4)$

Product in numerator = $\frac{-x^6}{4} + O(x^8)$

Thus $k=6$ and $L=-\frac{1}{4}$.

Without Big-Oh you can try writing as inequalities:

$$ \frac{x^{4}}{2} + ax^6 \ge e^{x^2} - x^2 + 1 \ge \frac{x^{4}}{2}$$

and

$$ \frac{x^2}{2} \ge 1 - \cos x \ge \frac{x^2}{2} - bx^4$$

Comment: Should be $-\frac{1}{4}$, right?

Comment: @PaulK: Err. Yes. Corrected. Thanks!

Comment: @Aryabhata Thank you for your response. Could you possibly make it more detailed? I have not yet learned what seems to be big o notation? thank you

Comment: @Kevin: Modified a little bit.